Help me show that $\max_{k \leq n}|X_k|$ is an adapted process
Setup
$(\Omega, F, P)$; probability space
Let $\{F_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ be a filtration, and $X=\{X_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ be an adapted process.
In addition, we define
$$
X^\ast_n = \max_{k\leq n}|X_k|.
$$
Then, we want to show that $X^\ast=\{X^\ast_n\}_{n=0,1,2,\ldots}$ is adapted.
My try
It is sufficient to show that
$$
\{X^\ast_n\in B\}\in F_n
$$
for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}, \forall B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).$
Now we know
$$
\{X_n\in B\}\in F_n
$$
because $X_n$ is adapted.
This is probably incorrect, but it seems to be a good idea to proceed with the transformation in this atmosphere:
$$
\{X^\ast_n\in B\} = \{\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|\in B\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^n \{|X_k|\in B\}\in F_n
$$
I am stuck because I cannot transform it properly.

It is sufficient to show that
$$
\{X^\ast_n\le  a\}\in F_n
$$
for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}, \forall a\in \mathbb{R}.$
$\{X^\ast_n\le a\} = \bigcap\limits_{k=0}^n \{|X_k|\le a\}\in F_n
$ since $\{|X_k| \le a\} \in F_k \subseteq F_n$ for each $k \le n$.

@KurtG. That was  a typo. Thanks for pointing out.
